AWS Codepipeline for a react web app using nodejs 14
        pipeline = pipelines.CodePipeline(self, "Os1Pipeline",
            synth=pipelines.ShellStep("Synth",
                # Use a connection created using the AWS console to authenticate to GitHub
                # Other sources are available.
                input=pipelines.CodePipelineSource.connection("twosvn/os1-platform-be", "aws",
                    connection_arn="arn:aws:codestar-connections:eu-north-1:767397986068:connection/416d1c42-1019-4d88-9fa8-db0d6b9e7d53"
                ),
                commands=["npm ci", "pwd", "python3 -m venv venv", "source venv/bin/activate", "pip3 install -r requirements.txt", "cdk synth"
                ],
                primary_output_directory='os1-be/cdk.out',
            )
        )

The error i'm getting is with my cdk.out. I've added my subdirectory there but no luck. currently my pipeline is in a Pipelines/os1-be/cdk.out
I want to create a cdkv2 pipeline for a react app i have. I connected the soure using codestar connection but it won't build.
I'm expecting it to build my web app. here is the error message i get.
added 665 packages, and audited 666 packages in 14s
59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
1 moderate severity vulnerability
To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
Run `npm audit` for details.
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:08.578134 Running command pwd
/codebuild/output/src989149853/src
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:08.582937 Running command python3 -m venv venv
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.647203 Running command source venv/bin/activate
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: source: not found
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.659890 Command did not exit successfully source venv/bin/activate exit status 127
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.667907 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.667924 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: source venv/bin/activate. Reason: exit status 127
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.696967 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.703592 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.703607 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.788761 Expanding base directory path: os1-be/cdk.out
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.790632 Assembling file list
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.790654 Expanding os1-be/cdk.out
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.793226 Skipping invalid file path os1-be/cdk.out
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.793558 Set report auto-discover timeout to 5 seconds
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.793590 Expanding base directory path:  .
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.795535 Assembling file list
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.795549 Expanding .
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.797649 Expanding file paths for base directory .
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.797659 Assembling file list
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.797663 Expanding **/*
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.861747 Found 3 file(s)
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.861866 Report auto-discover file discovery took 0.068308 seconds
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.862523 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/06/14 20:20:20.862552 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching base directory path found for os1-be/cdk.out
no matching base directory path found for os1-be/cdk.out


Does this answer your question? source command not found in sh shell
